# Docker image history at import from tar

Tags: image, docker, deployment, import

I want to be able to deliver my changes to QA department using Docker. My workflow is:

- Make changes
- Build image
- Save it as a tar
- Import it on another computer locally
- Restart compose with my image (containing my changes)

I can't load it to a registry due to a sticky management process and must deliver it as a tar. An image history is loosing during saving and import and when we try to up compose with a newly imported image it raises an error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

An image is inherited from a local image which in it's turn inherited from `ubuntu:16.04` image. In both images I added this line after `FROM` directive:

```
ENTRYPOINT bash
```

But had no luck and faced the same error.

**How to save/import image and be able to run containers using the image?**

Comment: What commands did you use for export and import? Please add those as well

Comment: @TarunLalwani, `save` to export and `import` to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `import` use `load`

```
docker load -i <exported.tar>
```

This will load all layers. When you do

```
docker import exported.tar image:tag
```

This will load all file system in a single layer of the image. If you need to add a CMD to it you can use

```
docker import -c 'CMD ["/bin/bash"]' exported.tar image:tag
```

So I would suggest using load instead of import.